# How can I pass variables to an svg file in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, svg, r-markdown, draw.io

I would like to input a draw.io diagram into my RMarkdown file. However, I want the numbers in the diagram (variable1, variable2, see image) to update with respect to the variables in a code chunk.
[image]

For example, if I write:

```
variable1 = 10
variable2 = 10
```

I want 10 to be visible in the diagram.

Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

I did not try anything yet, as I have no knowledge of svg files and don't even know if that is possible with R and RStudio.

Comment: Have you looked into this user-created R package? https://github.com/coolbutuseless/minidrawio

Comment: no I never heard of it actually. Thanks I'll definitely check it out :)